# Why the make error disappeared after re-bitbkake?

Tags: qt5, yocto

I'm trying to compile [AGL guppy](https://gerrit.automotivelinux.org/gerrit/gitweb?p=AGL/AGL-repo.git;a=blob;f=guppy_7.0.4.xml;h=0ede5a0b4b80606367026138a47c414807b15b75;hb=HEAD) with Qt 5.15.
So I forked the [meta-qt5](https://code.qt.io/cgit/yocto/meta-qt5.git/log/?h=5.15).

and add my custom config `qtbase_git.bbappend`:

```
PACKAGECONFIG += "eglfs gl gles2 linuxfb kms libinput"
PACKAGECONFIG[vsp2] = "-feature-vsp2,-no-feature-vsp2,v4l-utils,libv4l"
PACKAGECONFIG += "vsp2"
PACKAGECONFIG[gbm] = "-gbm,-no-gbm,libgbm"
PACKAGECONFIG += "gbm"
```

the first bitbake gives error:

```
| cd eglfs_kms_support/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/jiu/workspace_m3n-salvator-xs/build/tmp/work/aarch64-agl-linux/qtbase/5.15.1+gitAUTOINC+075d971fea-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/jiu/workspace_m3n-salvator-xs/build/tmp/work/aarch64-agl-linux/qtbase/5.15.1+gitAUTOINC+075d971fea-r0/git/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_kms_support/eglfs_kms_support.pro -qtconf /mnt/jiu/workspace_m3n-salvator-xs/build/tmp/work/aarch64-agl-linux/qtbase/5.15.1+gitAUTOINC+075d971fea-r0/build/bin/qt.conf ) && make -f Makefile
| cd eglfs_kms_vsp2/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/jiu/workspace_m3n-salvator-xs/build/tmp/work/aarch64-agl-linux/qtbase/5.15.1+gitAUTOINC+075d971fea-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/jiu/workspace_m3n-salvator-xs/build/tmp/work/aarch64-agl-linux/qtbase/5.15.1+gitAUTOINC+075d971fea-r0/git/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_kms_vsp2/eglfs_kms_vsp2.pro -qtconf /mnt/jiu/workspace_m3n-salvator-xs/build/tmp/work/aarch64-agl-linux/qtbase/5.15.1+gitAUTOINC+075d971fea-r0/build/bin/qt.conf ) && make -f Makefile
| cd eglfs_emu/ && ( test -e Makefile || /mnt/jiu/workspace_m3n-salvator-xs/build/tmp/work/aarch64-agl-linux/qtbase/5.15.1+gitAUTOINC+075d971fea-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qmake -o Makefile /mnt/jiu/workspace_m3n-salvator-xs/build/tmp/work/aarch64-agl-linux/qtbase/5.15.1+gitAUTOINC+075d971fea-r0/git/src/plugins/platforms/eglfs/deviceintegration/eglfs_emu/eglfs_emu.pro -qtconf /mnt/jiu/workspace_m3n-salvator-xs/build/tmp/work/aarch64-agl-linux/qtbase/5.15.1+gitAUTOINC+075d971fea-r0/build/bin/qt.conf ) && make -f Makefile
| Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: eglfs_kms_support-private
| Makefile:125: recipe for target 'sub-eglfs_kms_vsp2-make_first' failed
| make[5]: *** [sub-eglfs_kms_vsp2-make_first] Error 3
| make[5]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

but when I re-bitbake, the error disappeared.

I think it's because I am using multi-thread(j8) and the order of dependency of `qtbase` recipe was wrong.
So How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that can make that behavior to happen, at least in my experience, both occur when you have a subdir project:

1. When as you said, the subdir project has a wrong order for the subprojects, you fix that arranging the order in the .pro . For this to happen it doesn't matter if you are compiling in multi-thread or not. (also you can apply the dependency solution)
2. When you are compiling multi-thread and one subproject finish compiling before one with precedence. You workaround that compiling again, and you fix that assigning dependencies in the subdir pro file, like this:

```
SUBDIRS += SubA SubB SubC SubD ...
SubC.depends = SubA SubB
```